# Parsing a string including alphabetic characters and the regional characters(French, russian, chinese) in C/C++

Tags: c

As the title, I don't know how to parse a string including the alphabetic characters and the special characters from other languages in C. Anyone please help me how to distinguish them in C?. Do I need to install some optional components to help C accept the characters?(I'm in linux environment). Thanks very much for your reply.

Comment: There are some libraries, but you probably need to learn about basic character encoding before going any further, as you don't seem familiar with the concept.

Comment: What character encoding?  UTF-8?  UTF-16?  UCS-32?

Comment: Actually, I would like to use UTF-8 for encoding, and I guess I need to find out more about this before solving the problem. Thanks very much for your comments. However, I really appreciate if anyone can show me a sample code to do this in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you need to decide what [character encoding(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) you are going to use or support.  After that you will need to decide if you will keep the international strings in their native forms, or convert them using something like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/) into a single encoding in your application.

So first, as Laurent pointed out in a comment, you need to understand what you are trying to do (which is not going to be very easy--fair warning).  And take a look at what Joel Spolsky (co-founder of Stack Overflow) wrote many years ago: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your links John.

Comment: If they got you pointed in the right direction, you might consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.